# How prepopulate form on start workflow in alfresco?

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

When go to `http://localhost:8081/share/page/start-workflow?referrer=workflows&myWorkflowsLinkBack=true` you can select business process to start. After a new form with values is shown. Sp ia there a way to prepopulate this form? For example fill initiator `firstName` and `secondName` **before** workflow is started (just top show for user).